# Strategies to resize root partition

Tags: centos7, partition, disk-space-utilization

I currently have a CentOS 7 that appears to have been incorrectly partitioned, such that I've run out of space in /root. In normal circumstances, I'd migrated the roles running on this box and fix it. I sadly can't do that at this moment in time.

```
# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        20G   16G  2.4G  87% /
devtmpfs         16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            16G  1.6G   15G  10% /run
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md3        1.8T   52G  1.7T   3% /home
tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/1001
tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/992
tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/1002
tmpfs           6.0G   24K  6.0G   1% /mnt/nginxramdisk
tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/995
```

Obviously, I need to fix `/dev/root`.

Ideally, I'd take some space from `/dev/md3`, however, I am not sure if I can.

Looking at fstab, they are physical and ext4, so doing things online may be difficult.

```
<file system>   <mount point>   <type>  <options>   <dump>  <pass>
/dev/md2    /   ext4    errors=remount-ro   0   1
/dev/md3    /home   ext4    defaults    1   2
/dev/sda4   swap    swap    defaults    0   0
/dev/sdb4   swap    swap    defaults    0   0
proc        /proc   proc    defaults        0   0
sysfs       /sys    sysfs   defaults        0   0
tmpfs       /dev/shm    tmpfs   defaults    0   0
devpts      /dev/pts    devpts  defaults    0   0
```

Any ideas on how I can increase the size of `/root`?

Is it feasible for me to unmout `/home` and resize it with `resize2fs` to shrink it, then try to grow `/root` having brought it back online, and shrunk it?

As requested,

```
du -sh /*
233M    /app
0   /bin
132M    /boot
0   /dev
318M    /etc
49G /home
0   /lib
0   /lib64
16K /lost+found
4.0K    /media
8.0K    /mnt
2.2G    /opt
du: cannot access ‘/proc/2212/task/2212/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/2212/task/2212/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/2212/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/2212/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
0   /proc
273M    /root
1.6G    /run
0   /sbin
4.0K    /srv
0   /sys
1.1M    /tmp
4.1G    /usr
7.2G    /var
```

Comment: Can you find what's eating space on root and move / link that folder to something under /home?

Comment: @user16081-JoeT I've updated the post with a du of the root ... it doesn't look as simple.. ok, so I've cleaned up yum's cache, but that's bought me only 1G more

Comment: /var is your biggest folder and probably growing.  If you can just mount (or symlink) /var under /home then you don't need to repartition.  Trouble is you might not be able to move /var/ while your system is running.